# Facebook graph api, error when getting home connection

Tags: facebook

I get the following error when trying to query me/home

```
error: {
message: "An unknown error has occurred.",
type: "OAuthException",
code: 1
}
```

When I query me/feed it's working. And dev documentation says they need the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same problem, and guessing (hoping) it is a temporary bug.  I noticed if I explicitly specify the fields I'm interested in, then I don't see the error.  i.e.

/me/home?fields=from,created_time,description,id,link,message,name,picture,source,story,to,type,updated_time,caption,icon

If I add the "actions" field, the error comes back, so perhaps there is a problem there.

Comment: Seems to be working again, with the "actions" field.  So it must have been a temporary outage.